# Condition on solutions to Pell's equations

Tags: diophantine-equations

If $X_0$ and $Y_0$ be a solution to the Pell's equation of the form $X^2-DY^2=\pm 1$, are $X_0$ and $Y_0$ co-prime? If so, how to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\gcd(X_0,Y_0)=n>1$. Then $n|X^2,DY^2\implies n|X^2-DY^2=1$, a contradiction. Therefore  $\gcd(X_0,Y_0)=1$.

Comment: +1; I was going to write something along these lines, but you beat me to it;  minor detail:  OP said $\pm1$, though I think your proof still works